# Need help to optmize this sql script , i need this without nested query please help me

Tags: sql

```
SELECT   
    UserID AS UserIdToDelete 
FROM 
    CDICentral.dbo.UserDC AS ud
WHERE  
    (UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID 
                    FROM CVPLocal.dbo.CSWSecurity AS cs))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `EXCEPT`, Get Records From First Table which are absent in Second Table

```
SELECT   UserID AS UserIdToDelete FROM CDICentral.dbo.UserDC
EXCEPT
SELECT UserID FROM CVPLocal.dbo.CSWSecurity
```

Comment: as a rookie first time i am hearing this work "Except" thanks a Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

Best way is probably the use of the NOT EXISTS.
Anyway if you don't want ti use nested query try to join the 2 tables by useID (use Use indexes in order ti tweek your performance)